# Custom key-values on JsonFormatter logging (Quarkus)

Tags: java, json, logging, quarkus

I want to know if there is any way to create my custom key-value json logging with the library org.jboss.logging.Logger. I have this method:

```
void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {               
    ArrayList<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList(2);
    Formatter formatter = new JsonFormatter();
    ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler(formatter);
    handler.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    handlers.add(handler);
    InitialConfigurator.DELAYED_HANDLER.setHandlers((Handler[]) handlers.toArray(EmbeddedConfigurator.NO_HANDLERS));
    LOGGER.info("The application is starting...");
}
```

And that prints:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-10-25T12:49:35.948+01:00",
  "sequence": 2346,
  "loggerClassName": "org.jboss.logging.Logger",
  "loggerName": "ListenerBean",
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "The application is starting...",
  "threadName": "Quarkus Main Thread",
  "threadId": 75,
  "mdc": {
    
  },
  "ndc": "",
  "hostName": "les007817",
  "processName": "callmenow-dev.jar",
  "processId": 466416
}
```

I need to add to this log two more key-value ("key:"value"). How can I achieve that.

(I'm using **Quarkus**. I know there are libraries that do that, but I need a manual way)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Quarkus, you can use the Quarkiverse Logging Json Extension: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkiverse-logging-json. It provides support to do just that.